# Beautiful Soup not working in Pycharm

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to import beautiful soup in my script, but get a module not found error.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOnH0.png)

But the problem is that when i try to install it, i get the message below:

```
Ajays-MacBook-Pro:/ aj$ pip install bs4
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from bs4)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I tried importing bs4 in Jupyter notebook and it works without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use different version of Python in the PyCharm, you should add the Python in the `/anaconda` folder in the PyCharm settings.

Comment: Perfect! This worked. I also found a way to install bs4 from the Pycharm IDE , so both versions of Pycharm have it now.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install BeautifulSoup4 from the terminal in pycharm.
Then when you try to import it in your code you need to change this statement

`from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`

to this

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

That error will be solved.